# Regular expression to find all characters BUT the ones after numbers

Tags: java, regex

I am no good in regexps but i am struggling to find a way to change the case of the letters of a string from lower to capital in java

Java has a very nice method called toUpperCase() however, this does not really help me for two reasons.

First, i would like to have a reference for such a regexp, since i couldn't find it anywhere, and
Second because it will change the case in all characters.

There are cases however that i would like to keep a lower character to avoid confusion, and make it better looking.

```
Good   Bad
2i   =  2I
2o   =  2O
1st  = 1ST
2nd  = 2ND
etc...
```

Is it possible to add conditions as well? for example

```
"don't replace if the sequence 'st' appears after the number '1' even if there is a space between"
"don't replace if the sequence 'nd' appears after the number '2' even if there is a space between"
etc...
```

I was wondering if someone could assist me in generating a regexp to select those characters

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this if it is what you needed:

```
final String[] s = { "2 nd blah", 
                "1st foo", 
                "foo 2nd bar", 
                "blahblah1stfounditimmediately", 
                "blah 3rd foo", 
                "blah55th foo", 
                "66 th bar"
                 };
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(1 ?ST|2 ?ND|3 ?RD|\\d+ ?TH)");
        Matcher m = null;
        String t;
        for (final String x : s) {
            t = x.toUpperCase();
            m = p.matcher(t);
            while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(x + " ---> " + t.replaceAll(m.group(1), m.group(1).toLowerCase()));
            }
        }
```

the output of above codes:

```
2 nd blah ---> 2 nd BLAH
1st foo ---> 1st FOO
foo 2nd bar ---> FOO 2nd BAR
blahblah1stfounditimmediately ---> BLAHBLAH1stFOUNDITIMMEDIATELY
blah 3rd foo ---> BLAH 3rd FOO
blah55th foo ---> BLAH55th FOO
66 th bar ---> 66 th BAR
```

EDIT for better code format.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
var str = '2 nd';

if (!/\d+(\s*)(nd|st)/i.test(str)) {
    str = String(str).toUpperCase();
}​​​​​​​​​​

console.log(str);
```

​